# How do I get to these hidden folders

Tags: windows-10, directory-listing

The other day I was doing a SQL Restore and I noticed some odd folders on my system.
[image]

The ones that start with !!!!!

As you can see there are files in these directories.  I would like to get to these files but can't seem out how to.

I have tried un-hiding System Files in Explorer and I have tried from the command prompt

```
dir /ahs
```

[image]

with no luck.  What else can I try ?

To answer a comment below the `dir /ahs` only shows hidden folders Areas is not hidden
[image]

But what I find interesting is I can not find `$WINDOWS.~BT` in either list

Comment: Are you really looking at the same drive? For example, yours doesn't have a folder named `Areas` either.

Comment: It does, just areas is not hidden.  I am working off the same laptop.

Answer (score 0):

The files and folders aren't hidden, they have been deleted, so you need file recovery software. Google file recovery, I think there are free versions out there.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to run Explorer "as administrator".

2) Become an owner of full C:\ drive. Watch this video:
- How to Take Ownership of a File or Folder and Get Access to View and Edit Them: https://youtu.be/w67xXG01cy8

3) If You still can't get access to these files, try to use an "Unlocker" software.